# Reliable ways of generating cover/concealment at range

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, tactics

Are there any magical items that can be used in order to reliably generate concealment at range, but do not impair/effect the user?  Take the case of, say, an archer-archetype character.  They may wish to fight at approximately 15-25 squares of range, and ideally from cover.  However, not all battlefields will contain cover at the appropriate distances from the enemies.  Ideally, there exists some item that:

1. Provides a high degree of cover/concealment.
2. Does not inflict penalties on its owner/user.
3. Can be used repeatedly.
4. Does not scream to the enemy "HERE!  HE'S IN THIS SUSPICIOUS PLANT IN THE MIDDLE OF THE DESERT!"

Barring that, any items/powers which meet as many of those criteria as possible may be useful.

Comment: Why do you want the cover? For the bonus to defenses, or as a means to allow you to hide (number four suggests the latter) while attacking?

Comment: Ideally, both.  Hiding is, after all, a very excellent bonus to defense :)

Comment: What level and class? There are so very many options it's not even funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some items based on searching for `concealment`:

- Several different armors offer concealment as a `Power(encounter)`:

  - `Armor of Night` (AV p41) Lvl 14+ (cloth, leather)
  - `Shadowflow Armor` (PHB p231) Lvl 13+ (cloth, leather)
- Several items offer a `Power(Daily)` that creates a zone (sustain minor) that provides concealment:

  - `Bottled Smoke` (AV 168) Lvl 17
  - `Jar of Steam` ( AV 174) Lvl 7

---

As a power/feat idea, using two feats to multi-classing as Wizard and swap a utility power, you could get

`Blur` Wizard Utility 10 Daily:

> **Effect**: Until the end of the encounter, you gain a +2 power 
>   bonus to all defenses, and enemies 5 or more squares 
>   away from you cannot see you.

Answer (score 4):

**[Phantom Chasseurs](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2714)**

Level 18, feet:

> Property: if you move at least 3 squares on your turn, gain concealment until the end of your next turn.

Comment: You just made my rogue's day.